# Oauth2: best practice to keep access_token fresh?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm creating an app that integrates with several 3rd-party Oauth2 providers (think Zapier). The user adds a connection through Oauth2 which gives me a refresh token and access token and which I'm storing in a database.

What is the best practice to keep the access token fresh? Should I be running an async job (e.g. cron) that refreshes the access token every 30 minutes for every connection? If the user doesn't use my app for several days I'd like to still be able to access his 3rd-party data without having him to go through the Oauth2 consent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the best practice to keep the access token fresh? Should I be running an async job (e.g. cron) that refreshes the access token every 30 minutes for every connection?

Not necessarily. Wait till your API call fails. Check for a proper response such as "401 Unauthorized" which hints your access token is invalidated/expired. Once this happens use refresh token to renew the access token. If refresh token fails, then you have to fall back again and ask user to login again.

A refresh token can have a varying life time. It can be from few days to few months. For example check Google's explanation mentioning [long lived refresh tokens and possible expiry of them](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration). Also check how Azure AD mention about configurations related to [token lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-types).

So user not using app for few days (ex:- leave it and return after weekend) can be handled through proper validity configurations of tokens lifetimes. But be mindful about threats that could occur from long-lived, unmanaged tokens (ex:- due to token stealing).

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't want to risk expiring the refresh token since I may not call the API at all for possibly weeks. I would assume in this case some sort of cron job would need to be set up.

Comment: If your application require to keep the connection active then using refresh token and updating access token time to time is fine. But note that refresh token can expire due to token revocation or after using for some time (ex:- X number of token refresh). Check with your authorization server specifics to identify them. Also, make your configurable with time details, so that you do not want to change code whenever policies change.

Comment: Actually to correct myself, setting up a cron job does not solve the problem; i thought that the refresh token can itself be refreshed and have its expiration date extended, but no. E.g. the Google Oauth2 refresh token has an expiration of 100 day, so after 100 days there is no alternative to asking the user consent again. But then I wonder how companies like Zapier work, are they asking the user for consent every time the refresh token expires?

Comment: Simply yes. Long lasting refresh tokens are a threat. So it is best to design to accept refresh tokens expiration/invalidation. In such case take use to a re-login. This is similar to a browser cookie expiration

Comment: What about Async codes? It will ask for multiple tokens almost at the same time and all except one is invalid LOL

Comment: @Mat  Well, if the access token is expired, the programme should trigger a refresh OR new token obtaining strategy. This needs to be synchronous as there can be only one token state in your programme. 

For example, 401 handling filter(i.e - NG http interceptor) needs a state and avoid asyn retrying for new token.

Answer (score 1):

The [Oauth website](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/making-authenticated-requests/refreshing-an-access-token/) has a pretty informative answer

> The “expires_in” value is the number of seconds that the access token
> will be valid. It’s up to the service you’re using to decide how long
> access tokens will be valid, and may depend on the application or the
> organization’s own policies. You could use this timestamp to
> preemptively refresh your access tokens instead of waiting for a
> request with an expired token to fail. Some people like to get a new
> access token shortly before the current one will expire in order to
> save an HTTP request of an API call failing. While that is a perfectly
> fine optimization, it doesn’t stop you from still needing to handle
> the case where an API call fails if an access token expires before the
> expected time. Access tokens can expire for many reasons, such as the
> user revoking an app, or if the authorization server expires all
> tokens when a user changes their password.
>
> If you make an API request and the token has expired already, you’ll
> get back a response indicating as such. You can check for this
> specific error message, and then refresh the token and try the request
> again.

TLDR: I would only refresh the token when a request fails