# .NET Core : proper way to use refresh token middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0, refresh-token

I have a .NET Core application that talks to an API. I'm trying to figure out how to handle refresh tokens. The endpoints for refreshing tokens are available, but I'm having trouble using them correctly since the token's lifespan is short, causing issues after refreshing.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: The refresh token could be set for several days or several months.  More details, you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54740262/7609093).

Comment: Am not asking how long a token should last, or the best practice of how long you should keep a token am asking where in the application pipeline should you attempt to refresh the token

Comment: It depend on how you config the refresh token, normally, we will write a API method to let the client send the refresh token to ask for the new token. We will not put it inside the Middelware.

Comment: please drop an answer, any pattern is appreciated.